# Where should I keep my generated postman documentation?

Tags: postman

I found out that postman allows to create a documentation based on my collections and routes. I have a repository which is an API. Those routes are basically return reports from the DB (maybe filtered) that meet with the query. Currently we have a very unprofessional documentation for the API and I would like to use Postman to generate a professional one. As I understand from the postman documentation, I can share it. Basically I thought to have a "documentation" button in my main page which will lead me to the generated postman documentation (under same DNS). My question is what is the proper way to display the postman page? Should I keep a copy of the postman API documentation in my repository? Or does postman allow to do it in some other way? I just don't understand how to properly display it to the user and how to keep track of the documentation. As I understand I should keep it somewhere. But where and how?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to generate documentation locally, you can use a tool I created -
https://github.com/karthiks3000/postman-doc-gen

You can generate the HTML documentation and host it wherever you want (along with your APIs or post it to a confluence page or something).

I've also detailed how you can host the generated documentation along with your API's in a spring boot app [here](https://medium.com/@karthiks3000/hosting-api-documentation-with-postman-springboot-e3ac141a6663)

Answer (score 0):

Your Postman documentation should be linked from wherever it will be most likely discovered by your consumers. It is common to have multiple links to multiple documentation in a single portal. The Run in Postman button is also a good way to embed in our your documentation or portal. Here is Postman's reference implementation that shows one possible way of linking to your Postman documentation - http://developers.union.fashion/.